# Advanced Login on Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, doctrine

I run 3 websites: site1.com, site2.com and site3.com on Symfony 2 with the same database. On my entity "User" there is users from site1, site2 and site3. The entity "User" has a field websiteId to know on witch site the user registered. I would like to disable user registered on siteA to login on siteB. I don't see anything on the documentation to handle this case.

Comment: And your question is...

Comment: How to avoid user from site1 to login on site2?

Comment: Create a Custom Form Password Authenticator: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_password_authenticator.html

Answer (score 0):

There's more than 1 way to solve this but I think I'd set up user roles for each of the sites users i.e..

```
 [ROLE_USER_SITE_1]
 [ROLE_USER_SITE_2]
 [ROLE_USER_SITE_3]
```

This way, you should be able use symfonys built-in security to limit user access.